# Angular.js ng-if directive does not update between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive which i show depending on a binding to an object attribute in my main page in a side panel. and the ng-view directive which loads different content depending on the hash routing.it looks something like this.The root scope is on the  tag, and is the Main controller.

```
<body ng-controller="Main">
     <auth-panel ng-show="viewModel.panels.auth"></auth-panel>
     <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

in the main page the contents of the ng-view directive are loaded using the same controller as the body.which are loaded using the routing service in the config.
when im routing to the second page i use another controller which makes the viewModel.panels.auth into a true.

```
$routeProvider.when('/',{
    templateUrl : 'pages/views/main.html',
    controller  : 'Main'
});
$routeProvider.when('/peopleNPlaces',{
    templateUrl : 'pages/views/peopleNPlaces.html',
    controller  : 'PeopleNPlaces'
});
```

when im in the main page this attribute is false.
when i move to the next page  "PeopleNPlaces" it show up using the ng-if and the truthy value. BUT for some reason when i navigate back using the browsers back event, i can see by debuging that the Main controller runs and the value is set to a false, BUT the ng-if directive wont update and the directive "auth-panel" still shows, as if the binding wont work.

```
app.controller('Main',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.viewModel = {
        panels:{
            auth:false
        }
}]);

neura.controller('PeopleNPlaces',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.viewModel.panels.auth = true;
});
```

the directive looks like this.

```
 app.directive('authPanel',function(){

return {
    templateUrl:'js/directives/authPanel.html',
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
        viewModel:'='
    },
    link:function($element,$attrs,$scope){
        console.log();
    },
    controller:function($scope,$attrs){
        console.log();
    }
}
 });
```

i used ng-if a lot in the past and i know it should be binding to the value and hide & show the directive dynamically.
did anyone encounter this bug, or maybe im missing something?

Comment: I don't see ng-if anywhere in your code, do you mean the ng-show at auth-panel? I think the problem might be that the two scopes for the two controllers are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a surrounding div like

```
<body ng-controller="Main">
    <div ng-show="viewModel.panels.auth">
        <auth-panel></auth-panel>
    </div>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
```

Also why are you setting the controller both in the body and in the route provider? I would stick to the route provider and remove it from the body.